# Why is a Javascript function created with Function constructor unable to access other functions defined outside of it?

Tags: javascript, function

See the code below. Why does `test2()` cause an error while `test1()` does not? How can the error be avoided (without having to redefine the called function inside the constructor)?

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
var xyz = function (){
                var test1 = function () { getRandomInt(10, 20); };
                test1();  // runs with out problem 
                var test2 = new Function('getRandomInt(10, 20);');
                test2(); //results in "Uncaught ReferenceError: getRandomInt is not defined"
                };
```

Comment: I think it is a matter of scope. `getRandomInt()` probably doesn't exist in the context of the second one.

Comment: *Of course* it's a matter of scope. That's what the entire question is about.

Comment: Jarnal - Is all of the code shown inside some other function? (Also, other than out of curiosity about how it works, why would you want to use `new Function()` here?)

Comment: bfavaretto and @nnnnnn : Yes, the code is inside another function (inside an AngularJS controller as a matter of fact). The Function constructor is being used to create function from a string fetched from the database (yes I know the constructor is generally not the preferred way but in this case the requirement is to fetch the function from a database so I am open to any other suggestions to create the function from a string).

Comment: I can almost guarantee there is a better way than using `new Function(...);`

Comment: @JoeSimmons, care to back that statement with your suggested alternative?

Comment: There are many alternatives. I'd need to know exactly what you're doing with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming all that is inside another function (an IIFE, maybe?). Code created with `new Function` is evaluated in the global scope, and it seems `getRandomInt` is not available there.

Check these demonstrations on jsfiddle: [it works if unwrapped](http://jsfiddle.net/7wPK4/), [but not inside an IIFE](http://jsfiddle.net/7wPK4/1/).

If you need the code to be evaluated in the current scope, you have to use `eval`:

```
var test2 = eval('(function(){return getRandomInt(10, 20);})');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7wPK4/2/

#### References

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function
- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.2.1

Comment: @Jamal For example node modules are not in global scope, but create an IIFE behind the scenes.

Comment: @bfavaretto yes its inside another function. More details in my comment that I just added to the question.

Comment: @Jarnal So that's why. Did you understand my answer? If not, let me know what you don't get, and I'll try to explain better.

Comment: @bfavaretto, yes, thanks for your quick answer. So is there a way to avoid this error without resorting to defining the called function on the window/global object? Is there a way to evaluate the new Function in the scope from which it is called ?

Comment: @Jarnal Not with `new Function`, but a regular `eval` does the job: `var test2 = eval('(function(){return getRandomInt(10, 20);})');` - http://jsfiddle.net/7wPK4/2/

Comment: @bfavaretto, hmmm, so between these two choices (A) using the Function constructor and (B) using new eval(), which of these would be the lesser evil? Does the Function constructor create similar security loopholes as eval() does?

Comment: `new Function` is considered a bit less evil exactly because it does not use the current scope. In your case, eval is the only option. If the code you have in the database is trusted, you should be fine. @Jarnal

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) on MDN:

> Functions created with the Function constructor do not create closures
>   to their creation contexts; they always are created in the global
>   scope. When running them, they will only be able to access their own
>   local variables and global ones, not the ones from the scope in which
>   the Function constructor was called. This is different from using eval
>   with code for a function expression.

So maybe your `getRandomInt` isn't in the global scope? Would need to see the entire code, or a jsFiddle re-creating the problem.

Comment: +1 for the reference and the bit about change in context with 'use strict'.

Comment: @Jarnal: Actually, that bit is plain wrong. I've fixed MDN already.